# How can you duplicate a view programmatically in Swift? How does Auto-Layout affect the newly created View?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I've got a table view which display a number of dots depending on some other data. Each cell in the table view contains a different number, and needs to display a certain number of dots according to that number. So for example, cell 1 corresponds to 5 dots, cell 2 corresponds to 3 dots, so on.

Since all the cells contain at least one dot, I have created a prototype cell which contains a single dot (called a dotView, which is a custom View that I am using).

I would like to basically duplicate the dot several times to match the number that I need.

The dots are aligned and positioned vertically, so I just need to copy and paste the dotView above itself, but treat it as a separate view so I can access its' members without altering any of the other dotViews.

If successful, will I need to set the auto layout parameters myself? Or will it inherit some of the prototypes values?

Comment: Sometimes a stack view will help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do it if you're just designing things in the nib (storyboard). Any view you see in Interface Builder can be duplicated; just say Duplicate (or Option-drag). You will then have to configure the new copy completely.

You cannot, however, magically "copy and paste" an existing view in the interface *in code*, while the app is running. The standard way to do this sort of thing *in code* is to design the custom view in a *.xib* file. Then, whenever you need a new copy of this view, you load the nib and retrieve it. This is basically just an elaborate way of making a new but completely configured instance of this view (and all its subviews, settings in the nib, etc.). You will then need to insert the newly instantiated dot view manually (i.e. in code) into the interface wherever it is needed. Positioning it is up to you, and if it needs constraints, you will have to add them as well.

Comment: A huge failing of the overall iOS milieu is that there's no concept of a "model" or "prefab".  Indeed, it does exist in: cell views in tables and collections.  This is the reason one often has to use tables/cells in tortured ways, so as to have the concept of a "model" or "prefab".  Container views are almost there, in another 10 years someone at Apple will realize you should be able to use those like an ordinary prefab, anywhere!